# PHP Form post to TXT file on remote FTP

Tags: php, linux, windows, forms, ftp

Here is the script that writes form data to txt file on same server (Linux). On every post it generates new file.

```
$myfile='/home/mysite/public_html/nar/fis_'.date('D_Mi').'_'.date('dmY_Hi').'.txt';

$fh=fopen($myfile,"w"); 
    # Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark 
    fwrite($fh, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
    fwrite($fh,$upisufajl); 
    fclose($fh);
```

But now I need it to write on remote FTP server with username and password that is on Windows.

```
I have address: ftp://89.142.185.206/new_files/ and username and password.
```

What do I need to do? Examples would be appreciated.

Thanks guys

Comment: Write it and upload it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i assume that you have successfully written content to your text file, make use of this below script to login to FTP Server to upload your text file.

```
<?php
     $ftp_server="";
     $ftp_user_name="";
     $ftp_user_pass="";
     $file = "";//your textfile
     $remote_file = "remfile.txt";


     $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
     $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
     if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
        exit;
     } else {
        echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
        exit;
        }
     ftp_close($conn_id);
```